# Does $|(a+b)/2|^p +|(a-b)/2|^p \le \frac{|a|^p}{2} + \frac{|b|^p}{2}$ hold for any $p>1, a, b\in\mathbb R$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, inequality

Let $p\in (1, +\infty)$.
Does the inequality
$$|(a+b)/2|^p +|(a-b)/2|^p \le \frac{|a|^p}{2} + \frac{|b|^p}{2}.$$
hold for any $a, b\in\mathbb{R}$?

I was discussing yesterday about that with my class mates. I say that it is true because
$$t\mapsto |t|^p$$
is convexity for any $p\in (1, +\infty)$. They say no, but it holds only for $p\ge 2$.

Anyone could please help me with that?

Comment: Jensen's inequlity gives $|a|^{p}+|b|^{p}$ instead of $(|a|^{p}+|b|^{p})/2$

Comment: Your inequality seems to fail for $p\in(1,2)$. Just fix $b$ and let $a\to+\infty$, which leads to $2^{1-p}\leq 2^{-1}$, which is false for $p\in(1,2)$.

Comment: @Feng Even simpler, just let $a = 0$ and there'll be the same conclusion.

Comment: @BrunoB Yesssss!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $b=0$ and $a\neq 0$. Then you want
$$
2\cdot \frac{|a|^p}{2^{p}} \leq \frac{|a|^p}{2}
$$
or, equivalently,
$$
4 \leq 2^p.
$$
Clearly, this is false for $p < 2$.